# How to add listener in recyclerview when image is ready for display

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Currently, I have an app that uses Picasso to download images and display them in a recyclerview.

I want to change my logic by totally doing away with Picasso and downloading images in the background when the app is initially installed. During succeeding runs of the app, the images will be displayed from internal storage.

So, how would I let the recyclerview know that the image is ready for display after it has been successfully saved in internal storage? I'd prefer if they aren't shown all at once because that would take too long, but show each image as the download is completed (kind of similar to how Picasso does it).

This is my current onBindViewHolder code:

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(rawHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val holder = rawHolder as CustomVH
        holder.resourcesByCategory = resourcesByCategory[position]

        val dir : String = utils.getInternalDirectory("Covers") + "/CoverBookId" +  resourcesByCategory[position].id + ".jpg"
        val bookCover = File(dir)
        if (bookCover.exists()) {
            if (holder.bmp != null) {
                holder.bmp!!.recycle()
            }

            holder.resourceCover.setImageBitmap(null)
            val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565
            holder.bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(FileInputStream(bookCover), null, options)

            if (holder.bmp != null) {
                holder.bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(holder.bmp, 150,180, true)
                holder.resourceCover.setImageBitmap(holder.bmp!!)
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: I think AsyncTask is what you need https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: I don't (and probably nobody will) recommend to do it manually, please see https://medium.com/@afomic/android-image-processing-libraries-a68e306f58d1